# get record in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
SELECT `sms_id`, 
       `u_id`, 
       `sender_id`, 
       `mobile_no`, 
       `message`, 
       `campaign_name`, 
       `status`, 
       `request_id`, 
       `route_id`, 
       `totalnumber`, 
       `msgcreadit`, 
       `date1`, 
       `deductbal`, 
       `submited` 
FROM   `send_sms` 
WHERE  1
```

I want to select `u_id` whose `status ="pending"`, but I want the latest pending status according to the `[date1]` date field and I also want the count of individual `u_id`s with `status ="pending"`.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM `send_sms` s
WHERE s.status = 'pending' AND
      s.date1 = (SELECT MAX(s2.date1) FROM send_sms s2 WHERE s2.u_id = s.u_id and s2.status = 'pending');
```

Comment: I got empty result :(

Comment: I would add `AND s.status = 'pending'` into subquery `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM `send_sms` s
LEFT JOIN `send_sms` s2
ON s.date1 < s2.date1
  AND s2.u_id = s.u_id
  AND s2.status = 'pending' 
WHERE s.status = 'pending' 
  AND s2.status IS NULL
```

Comment: query is correct but i also want count of all u_id whose  status  is pending with this result just one more correction please

Comment: all `u_id`!? so you want to get for example 10 or **1000** rows with duplicate value of **1000** in every row?